# Сортировка по двум / нескольким критериям

Tags: python, сортировка

Требуется функцией sorted вернуть список, отсортированный по двум критериям, как это сделать?

К примеру есть список строк, которые надо отсортировать по длине, а строки одной длины в алфавитном порядке между собой

Comment: Ну к примеру есть список строк, которые надо отсортировать по длине, а строки одной длины в алфавитном порядке между собой

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> есть список строк, которые надо отсортировать по длине, а строки одной
>   длины в алфавитном порядке между собой

Пример:

```
In [29]: strings = ['cc', 'aa', 'bbb', 'aaa', 'ddd', 'bb']

In [30]: sorted(strings, key=lambda x: (len(x), x))
Out[30]: ['aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'aaa', 'bbb', 'ddd']
```

---

Другой пример - сортируем список списков сначала по второму элементу (по возрастанию), а потом по третьему элементу (по убыванию):

```
In [37]: data = [["Max", "Mustermann", 66], ["John", "Doe", 33], ["Janie ", "Doe", 44]]

In [38]: sorted(data, key=lambda x: (x[1], -x[2]))
Out[38]: [['Janie ', 'Doe', 44], ['John', 'Doe', 33], ['Max', 'Mustermann', 66]]
```

---

Менее тривиальный пример - сортируем список имен и фамилий - сначала сортируем по фамилии в алфавитном порядке, затем по имени в обратном порядке:

```
In [47]: data = [["Max", "Mustermann"], ["John", "Doe"], ["Janie", "Doe"], ["Abigale", "Doe"]]

In [48]: sorted(data, key=lambda x: (x[1], [-ord(c) for c in x[0]]))
Out[48]: [['John', 'Doe'], ['Janie', 'Doe'], ['Abigale', 'Doe'], ['Max', 'Mustermann']]
```